# compare number elements in array of char

Tags: c++

I am new to programming and I want to get an unlimited input of numbers from user, and I need to compare each number to 4 or 7; if the number is 4 or 7, I will increase counter.

The issue is that the if condition `if(arr[i]!='4' || arr[i]!='7')` is executed even if the number is 4 or 7.

I tried to implement another if by comparing ASCII code >>>  `if(arr[i]!=0x34 || arr[i]!=0x37)` but this solution also doesn't work.

Can you help me to find the issue?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int counter=0;
    char arr[]={};                 
    cin >> arr;

    for (int i=0 ; i<strlen(arr)-1 ; i++)
    {
          if(arr[i]!='4' || arr[i]!='7')
          {
             cout << "NO" << endl;
             counter=0;                 
             break;
          }else
            counter++;
    }
    cout << counter << endl;
    if(counter==4 || counter==7)
    cout << "YES" << endl;

}
```

Comment: If `arr[i]=='4'`, what is the value of `arr[i]!='7'`?

Comment: Obviously your expression `if(arr[i]!='4' || arr[i]!='7')` is always true; Did you mean `if(arr[i]!='4' && arr[i]!='7')` ?

Comment: You obviously want to increment your counter if, in plain English: "arr[i] is equal to 4 or arr[i] is equal to 7". You write this in C++ as `(arr[i] == '4' || arr[i] == '7')`. To find the negation of a boolean statement, you apply [De Morgan's Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws), or simply leave the "not" outside the parentheses. `!(arr[i] == '4' || arr[i] == '7')` is just as valid as `(arr[i] != '4' && arr[i] != '7')`.

Comment: Every number is either not equal to 4 or not equal to 7. That's your mistake.

Comment: thank you guys , it solved by (arr[i] != '4' && arr[i] != '7') . my mistake was ||

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program has [*undefined behavior*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior), because this

```
char arr[]={};
```

creates an array of length zero. This is not even allowed in standard C++. If your compiler didn't complain about it, then that is because it is using a non-standard language extension.

In any case, the array has length zero. You then try to write to it with

```
 cin >> arr;
```

which causes the array to be accessed out-of-bounds, no matter how long the given input is. This will cause undefined behavior and you will not have any guarantee whatsoever on how the program will behave.

Never use `char` arrays to store strings, especially not user input. Use `std::string` instead:

```
 std::string arr;
 cin >> arr;
```

Then instead of `strlen(arr)` you should use `arr.size()`.

---

I am pretty sure you have further logic errors in your program (see question comments). But before you fix the program logic, you should make sure that you are writing a valid program in the first place.

Comment: than you so much for your help ,

strlen(arr) >> for array of char
arr.size >> for string
sizeof(arr) >> what is the usage of it??

Comment: @logan_92 `sizeof(arr)` gives the size of the `std::string` object itself, not the length of the string it contains. You should rarely need to use `sizeof` for anything. If you want to know the size of some container-like object, e.g. an array, then use `std::size` instead.